# Show that $P(X_1 = x_1 \text{ and } X_2 = x_2) = P(X_1 = x_1)P(X_2 = x_2)$ implies

Tags: probability

Show that for $X_1$ and $X_2$ discrete random variables $$P(X_1 = x_1 \text{ and } X_2 = x_2) = P(X_1 = x_1)P(X_2 = x_2)$$

implies that $$P(X_1 \in A \text{ and } X_2 \in B) = P(X_1 \in A)P(X_2 \in B)$$ for any sets $A,B$ of real values.

I feel as though this should be completely obvious, I have been trying to find a way to prove it however - could someone guide me the right way?

Comment: think about it in terms of finite sets: if I say that  $A$ has two elements $a_1,a_2$ and $B$ has two elements $b_1,b_2$, what can you say about it?

Comment: well this is the thing, how I was thinking about it was: since the definition holds for any pair $(x_1,x_2)$ we have it holds for all $x_1 in X_1$ and for all $x_2 in X_2$, so in terms of sets this is "like" $X_1 \in A$ and $X_2 \in B$ but I'm not really sure if this is "formal"

Comment: given two events, $E_1$ and $E_2$, if they are incompatible (that is $P(E_1\cap E_2)=0$) then $P(E_1\cup E_2)=P(E_1)+P(E_2)$.
the event "$X_1\in A$ and $X_2\in B$" is the union of the events "$X_1=x_1\in A$ and $X_2=x_2\in B$", so..

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X = \{(e_i, f_j) \}_{i \in \{1, \dots, n\}, j \in \{1, \dots, m\}} \subset [a, b]\times [c, d]$, where $X$ is the set of ordered pairs over which $(X_1, X_2)$ has nonzero probability. Then

$$\begin{align}
P(X_1 \in [a, b], X_2 \in [c, d]) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m}P(X_1 = e_i, X_2 = f_j) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m}P(X_1 = e_i)P( X_2 = f_j) \\
&= \left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(X_1 = e_i)\right]\left[\sum_{j=1}^{m}P( X_2 = f_j) \right] \\
&= P(X_1 \in [a, b])P(X_2 \in [c, d])\text{.}
\end{align}$$
If $n\to\infty$ or $m \to \infty$, take the appropriate limits.